# JavaFX Pagination: setPageCount(int) calls the page factory again but does not show the page

Tags: java, javafx, pagination, javafx-8

### Pre-story:

Ok so i had another problem with a custom pagination control and thought i had figure out why it didn't work as expected. However it still didn't work. So i created a min example to find out what was happening and if something else in my code was messing it up.

### Problem

When setting the page count, the page factory gets called again, but the page that is being returned is not displayed. And I just can't figure out why.

---

**Additional information for the code example:**

If you comment out the setPageCount(4) the "initial page" will load. However when you do not comment it out, everything will only work if you switch pages or resize.

**Edit:** I was also wondering why the page factory is called at all if my current page is lower then the new page count. seems so weird - shouldn't it only call the page factory, if my new page count is lower then my current page index in addition to changing the current page index to 0?

---

### Code - Minimal Working Example

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main  extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Pagination pagination = new Pagination();

        pagination.setPageFactory( index -> {
            TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
            System.out.println("Trace: start: createTilePane");
            System.out.println("TilePane: " + tilePane);

            tilePane.widthProperty().addListener( observable -> {
                System.out.println("WidthProperty-Listener");
                System.out.println("tilePane: w: " + tilePane.getWidth() + "; h: " + tilePane.getHeight());
            });
            tilePane.heightProperty().addListener( observable -> {
                System.out.println("HeightProperty-Listener");
                System.out.println("tilePane: w: " + tilePane.getWidth() + "; h: " + tilePane.getHeight());
                pagination.setPageCount(4);
            });
            tilePane.setOnMouseClicked( event -> {
                System.out.println("Trace: onMouseClicked()");
                System.out.println("tilePane: " + tilePane);
            });
            tilePane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BEIGE, null, null)));


            System.out.println("Trace: end: createTilePane");
            return tilePane;
        });

        root.getChildren().add(pagination);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to achieve? By the way, setting the pagecount when the height of the pagination control changes, doesn't make any sense at all. Why don't you set it outside of the factory?

Comment: I have a number of cells that I want to display in a paginated view. When resizing the amount of cells that fit on one page changes and so does the page count accordingly. When resizing I recalculate the number of items per page and the corresponding page count. To do that I need to change the page count on resize, which seems to be making problems. It looks like my approach is flawed. Run later works for initial load for example, but if I use it for when switching pages the width and height aren't set yet. It's such a weird behavior. It seems like pagination just wasn't built for changing

Comment: The page count on resize

Comment: I deleted my other question, but can undelete it in a minute, in that question is my old code that I rewrote a dozen times by now and a few Screenshots

Comment: I thought a min example would work better

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120127/pagination-tilepane-setting-page-count-results-in-layout-being-messed-up-on-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "just" had to use Platform.runlater to set the pagination and rethink the flow of the whole thing. There is still some optimisation to be done, but the core problem of the question is answered.

This is the solution:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static final double CELL_HEIGHT = 60;
    private static final double CELL_WIDTH = 100;
    private static final double CELL_H_GAP = 10;
    private static final double CELL_V_GAP = 10;
    private static final int ITEM_COUNT = 100;

    private Pagination pagination;
    private int itemCount; // Count of items that fit on a page

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        pagination = new Pagination();
        pagination.setPageFactory(this::pageFactory);

        root.getChildren().add(pagination);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private StackPane pageFactory( int pageIndex ) {
        TilePane page = new TilePane();
        StackPane pageContainer = new StackPane(page);
        pageContainer.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        initPage(page);
        addListeners(pageContainer, page);
        fillPage(page, pageIndex);

        return pageContainer;
    }

    private void initPage( TilePane page ) {
        page.setHgap(CELL_H_GAP);
        page.setVgap(CELL_V_GAP);
        page.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BEIGE, null, null)));
    }

    private void addListeners ( StackPane pageContainer, TilePane page) {
        pageContainer.heightProperty().addListener( observable -> {
            if (pageContainer.getWidth() != 0 && pageContainer.getHeight() != 0) {
                onResize(pageContainer, page);
            }
        });
        pageContainer.widthProperty().addListener( observable -> {
            if (pageContainer.getWidth() != 0 && pageContainer.getHeight() != 0) {
                onResize(pageContainer, page);
            }
        });
    }

    private void onResize ( StackPane pageContainer, TilePane page ) {
        int itemCountHorizontal = 1;
        int itemCountVertical = 1;
        int itemCount;
        int pageCount;

        itemCountHorizontal += ( pageContainer.getWidth() - CELL_WIDTH - 1 ) / ( CELL_WIDTH + CELL_H_GAP );
        itemCountVertical += (pageContainer.getHeight() - CELL_HEIGHT - 1 ) / ( CELL_HEIGHT + CELL_V_GAP );
        itemCount = itemCountHorizontal * itemCountVertical;
        itemCount = ( itemCount == 0 ) ? 1 : itemCount;

        pageCount = ITEM_COUNT / itemCount + 1;

        page.setMinWidth( (CELL_WIDTH * itemCountHorizontal) + (CELL_H_GAP * (itemCountHorizontal-1)) );
        page.setMaxWidth( (CELL_WIDTH * itemCountHorizontal) + (CELL_H_GAP * (itemCountHorizontal-1)) );
        page.setMinHeight( (CELL_HEIGHT * itemCountVertical) + (CELL_V_GAP * (itemCountVertical-1)) );
        page.setMaxHeight( (CELL_HEIGHT * itemCountVertical) + (CELL_V_GAP * (itemCountVertical-1)) );

        if ( pagination.getPageCount() != pageCount ) {
            Platform.runLater( () -> {
                pagination.setPageCount(pageCount);
            });
        } else if ( this.itemCount != itemCount ){
            // If item count changed, rebuild the page
            this.itemCount = itemCount;
            page.getChildren().clear();
            fillPage(page, pagination.getCurrentPageIndex());
        }
    }

    private void fillPage ( TilePane page, int pageIndex ) {
        int startIndex = pageIndex * itemCount;
        int endIndex = Math.min( ITEM_COUNT, startIndex+itemCount );
        for ( int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++ ) {
            page.getChildren().add(cellFactory("C" + (i+1)));
        }
    }

    private Pane cellFactory( String cellText ) {
        StackPane cell = new StackPane();

        cell.setMaxHeight(CELL_HEIGHT);
        cell.setMinHeight(CELL_HEIGHT);
        cell.setMaxWidth(CELL_WIDTH);
        cell.setMinWidth(CELL_WIDTH);
        cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        cell.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY, null, null)));

        cell.getChildren().add(new Label(cellText));

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this. I'm using spinners to be more flexible in the demonstration:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TilesOnAGrid extends Application {

    Pagination pagination = new Pagination();

    Spinner<Integer> totalSpinner = new Spinner<Integer>(0, 30, 12);
    Spinner<Integer> rowSpinner = new Spinner<Integer>(1, 5, 2);
    Spinner<Integer> colSpinner = new Spinner<Integer>(1, 5, 2);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        pagination.setPageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {
            @Override
            public Node call(Integer index) {

                StackPane page = new StackPane();

                GridPane grid = new GridPane();

                grid.setHgap(10);
                grid.setVgap(10);
                grid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));

                int total = totalSpinner.getValue();
                int rows = rowSpinner.getValue();
                int cols = colSpinner.getValue();

                int offset = rows * cols * index;

                for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {

                        offset++;

                        if (offset > total)
                            break;

                        StackPane container = new StackPane();
                        container.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightgrey");

                        Label label = new Label("Item Nr. " + offset);
                        container.getChildren().add(label);

                        GridPane.setRowIndex(container, row);
                        GridPane.setColumnIndex(container, col);
                        GridPane.setHgrow(container, Priority.ALWAYS);
                        GridPane.setVgrow(container, Priority.ALWAYS);

                        grid.getChildren().add(container);
                    }
                }

                page.getChildren().add(grid);

                return page;
            }
        });

        totalSpinner.valueProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> layoutItems());
        rowSpinner.valueProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> layoutItems());
        colSpinner.valueProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> layoutItems());

        HBox toolbar = new HBox();
        toolbar.setPadding(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
        toolbar.setSpacing(5);
        toolbar.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Total"), totalSpinner, new Label("Columns"), colSpinner, new Label("Rows"), rowSpinner);

        root.setTop(toolbar);
        root.setCenter(pagination);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        layoutItems();

    }

    private void layoutItems() {

        int total = totalSpinner.getValue();
        int rows = rowSpinner.getValue();
        int cols = colSpinner.getValue();

        int pages = (int) Math.ceil(total / (double) (rows * cols));

        pagination.setPageCount(pages);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Regarding your code, you shouldn't change the page count in the factory. And if you need the changes depending on width / height, you can add a listener to root

```
root.heightProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> layoutItems());
root.widthProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> layoutItems());
```

or whatever your pagination container is and calculate the rows / columns accordingly.

---

**Edit**

Here's an example which considers cell width and height when you click the "Use Resizing" checkbox, i. e. controls the pagination while you resize the parent. Changing rows/columns should work now as well. I'm sending a custom event to trigger an update.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TilesOnAGrid extends Application {

    StackPane currentPageContainer = null;

    Pagination pagination = new Pagination();

    double minColWidth = 300;
    double minRowHeight = 300;

    Spinner<Integer> totalSpinner = new Spinner<Integer>(0, 30, 12);
    Spinner<Integer> rowSpinner = new Spinner<Integer>(1, 5, 2);
    Spinner<Integer> colSpinner = new Spinner<Integer>(1, 5, 2);

    BorderPane root;

    CheckBox useResizeCheckBox;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        root = new BorderPane();

        pagination.setPageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {
            @Override
            public Node call(Integer index) {

                currentPageContainer = createPage(index);
                currentPageContainer.addEventHandler(MyEvent.UPDATE, new MyEventHandler());

                return currentPageContainer;

            }
        });

        root.heightProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> layoutItems());
        root.widthProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> layoutItems());
        pagination.currentPageIndexProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> layoutItems());
        pagination.pageCountProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> layoutItems());

        totalSpinner.valueProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> layoutItems());
        rowSpinner.valueProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> layoutItems());
        colSpinner.valueProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Number>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> layoutItems());

        Label totalLabel = new Label("Total");
        Label rowsLabel = new Label("Rows");
        Label columnsLabel = new Label("Columns");

        useResizeCheckBox = new CheckBox("Use Resizing");
        useResizeCheckBox.selectedProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<Boolean>) (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            rowSpinner.setVisible(!newValue);
            colSpinner.setVisible(!newValue);
            rowsLabel.setVisible(!newValue);
            columnsLabel.setVisible(!newValue);

            layoutItems();

        });

        HBox toolbar = new HBox();
        toolbar.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        toolbar.setSpacing(5);
        toolbar.getChildren().addAll(useResizeCheckBox, totalLabel, totalSpinner, columnsLabel, colSpinner, rowsLabel, rowSpinner);

        root.setTop(toolbar);
        root.setCenter(pagination);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 800);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        layoutItems();

    }

    public int getRows() {

        if (useResizeCheckBox.isSelected()) {
            return (int) Math.ceil(root.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / minRowHeight);
        } else {
            return rowSpinner.getValue();
        }

    }

    public int getCols() {

        if (useResizeCheckBox.isSelected()) {
            return (int) Math.ceil(root.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / minColWidth);
        } else {
            return colSpinner.getValue();
        }

    }

    private void layoutItems() {

        int total = totalSpinner.getValue();
        int rows = getRows();
        int cols = getCols();

        int pages = (int) Math.ceil(total / (double) (rows * cols));

        pagination.setPageCount(pages);

        if (currentPageContainer != null) {
            MyEvent myEvent = new MyEvent(pagination.getCurrentPageIndex());
            currentPageContainer.fireEvent(myEvent);
        }
    }

    public StackPane createPage(Integer index) {

        StackPane page = new StackPane();

        page.getChildren().setAll(getGrid(index));

        return page;
    }

    public GridPane getGrid(Integer index) {

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));

        int total = totalSpinner.getValue();
        int rows = getRows();
        int cols = getCols();

        int offset = rows * cols * index;

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {

                offset++;

                StackPane container = new StackPane();

                Label label;
                if (offset <= total) {

                    container.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightgrey");
                    label = new Label("Item Nr. " + offset);

                } else {

                    label = new Label("");

                }

                container.getChildren().add(label);

                GridPane.setRowIndex(container, row);
                GridPane.setColumnIndex(container, col);
                GridPane.setHgrow(container, Priority.ALWAYS);
                GridPane.setVgrow(container, Priority.ALWAYS);

                grid.getChildren().add(container);
            }
        }

        return grid;
    }

    static class MyEvent extends Event {

        public static final EventType<MyEvent> UPDATE = new EventType<>(Event.ANY, "UPDATE");

        int index = 1;

        public MyEvent(int index) {
            super(UPDATE);
            this.index = index;
        }

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

    }

    private class MyEventHandler implements EventHandler<MyEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(MyEvent event) {

            currentPageContainer.getChildren().setAll(getGrid(event.getIndex()));

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Will look into your answer tonight and see if I can get it to work with a tile pane instead of a grid pane and dynamic sizing.

Comment: Not really relevant, but your example has a bug :D - using total:12 columns:3 and rows:2 and then setting columns:4 will not use 4 columns but stay at 3

Comment: I updated the answer with information where you should put the width/height listener. In case you need more help with that, let me know. Oh, didn't notice. I guess it's because all fits on the page, the paginator isn't changed and the event isn't fired, hence the factory method isn't called.

Comment: Ok so the main Problem was, that a change listener alone wasn't enough, runLater alone wasn't enough and i needed to not create a new page, but just clear the old one and add the cells again. Your answer unfortunately didn't help a lot, but it made me rebuilt it from scratch while really thinking about it. [Could you check if I made any ugly mistakes and either add this code to your answer or add a revisioned version of it - to make your answer complete](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d2f4e0432947df9b9f57)

Comment: My new code still has an issue with dividing my zero if i resize to a very small width, but ill look at that tomorrow after i got some sleep :D

Comment: This fixes the divide by zero issue: ```maxCellCount = maxCellCount == 0 ? 1 : maxCellCount;```

Comment: I updated my answer with an example that considers pagination during resizing, depending on whether you selected the checkbox or not. The row/col update should work as well, I'm using a custom event for the update. Feel free to answer your own question with your code, I'm not interested in the bounty, only needed a little challenge.

Comment: You helped me find the answer. So i awarded the bounty to you :)

Comment: Thank you! Glad I could help :-)